# Attempt to copy files from google cloud bucket to VM instance using gsutil is falling after reaching size limit

Tags: virtual-machines, google-cloud-platform, gsutil

I have a bucket with a file whose size is larger than 11 GB. I note that I can access all bucket's data from the standard google cloud console. Unfortunately, this console has very limited configurations since, I believe, it was primarily thought of as a tool to manage files and small operations within google cloud.

To better analyze my data I create a VM instance with 32 GB RAM. The problem is: once I am inside the VM instance I can no longer access the data from my bucket. After a bit of research I figure out that I can copy files from my bucket to my instance using:

```
gsutil -m cp -r gs://<my-bucket>/* .
```

I thought I have found a solution, but the operation stop after reaching 39%:

```
- [1/2 files][  4.4 GiB/ 11.2 GiB]  39% Done     0.0 B/s
```

I don't know what configuration my VM must have to complete this operation successfully or if the problem is with the VM at all.

Now, I just start to use google cloud and I'm in no way sure that I'm doing the right thing here. Is this the standard procedure for use bucket data within a VM instance? How can I copy large files from bucket to my VM instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is: once I am inside the VM instance I can no longer
> access the data from my bucket

Maybe you have [Access Control Lists](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/lists) set in some of your bucket folders.

You can use your account in the VM by `gcloud auth login`.